# Is it possible to use nested ScrollView? 

Tags: android

I have a **ScrollView** over the complete view. And in the same view I am having a smaller **ScrollView** which scrolls some text. The problem I am facing is that when I try scrolling the smaller ScrollView I can hardly scroll it. It is the main ScrollView which keeps on scrolling.
I tried using the following

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.article);
    if(scrollText.isInTouchMode())
    {
        scrollArticle.setEnabled(false);
    }  
    /*  

    Some code  

    */  

}
```

But it didn't work. What might be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in putting `ScrollView` inside another `ScrollView`. It wouldn't work. Try rethink your UI.

Comment: When I touch the smaller scrollView thrice consecutively, the scroll works fine. But not in one go.

Comment: It may work, but with some problems, like yours. It's strongly not recommended doing.

Comment: ScrollView inside ScrollView is not recommended period. Your UI needs a rethink.

Comment: It depends on your needs. Do you really need second ScrollView?

Comment: Yes, I need the second scrollview in a TextView. The text is too long. In the same page I also have a tableLayout for displaying few results. For that also I nedd a scrollView to scroll the table.

Comment: May be `TabActivity` fits your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Someone in google releases a library, 
[Synchronized scrolling](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt) which makes multiple scrollviews be scrolled sequentially.

This may help you.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, references tend to get stale over time. Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very old question but it's worth to mention that there is `NestedScrollView` in [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Scroll view introduced in API 22 .Try using [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)